# How to update a wallet object in Android Pay?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, curl, google-api, android-pay

I'm working with "Save to Android Pay" API and I'm trying to update one of my objects. According to [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/support/testing#update-an-object-or-class).

One way to achieve it is by using the cURL commands and follow these steps:

1. Get a token

> `java -jar TokenUtil.jar serviceAccountEmailAddress pathToPrivateKey`

2. Save the specific object to a text file

> `curl -X GET https://www.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/walletObjectType/resourceId -H "Authorization: Bearer bearerToken" > myobjectfile.txt`

3. make the changes I wish to make in the file (and increase the version value by 1)
4. Push the updated file back to the server.

> `curl -X PUT https://www.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/walletObjectType/resourceId -H "Authorization: Bearer bearerToken" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d myobjectfile.txt`

Steps 1 - 3 work fine but when I try to push the object back to the server I get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
         "errors": [
                   {
                   "domain": "global",
                   "reason": "parseError",
                   "message": "Parse Error"
                   }
                   ],
         "code": 400,
         "message": "Parse Error"
         }
}
```

Since all I changed in the file is the version (and maybe one character in some title, just to see change) I do not understand why am I getting a parse error as `myobjectfile.txt` came from the server and its internal structure was not built by me.

Comment: What's this got to do with GAE?

Comment: Save to Android Pay quick start project is using Google App Engine. See details here: https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/samples/quickstart-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took them a while but Google finally solved their bug and shared their solution with me (hopefully they will update their API soon, too):

•   The file should be a `.json` file rather than a `.txt` file.

•   There should be an `@` sign before the file name in the PUT command:

> `curl -X PUT
>   https://www.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/walletObjectType/resourceId
>   -H "Authorization: Bearer bearerToken" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @myobjectfile.json`

After applying these changes, I was able to update my object.